# Combine on tableGrob objects fails when used serially in a loop?

Tags: r, gridextra

Everyone I am trying to build tableGrob objects dynamically as new data arrives and I generate results as they become availale to me. Here is an attempt I made to generate such tables but for some reason the `combine()` function is not working as expected.

My code is as follows:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

alphabets <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",3))
numbers <- c(rep(c(1,2,3), 3))

df1 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets[1:4],numbers=numbers[1:4])
df2 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets[1:4],numbers=numbers[1:4])
df3 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets,numbers=numbers)

tab1 <- tableGrob(df1,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)
tab2 <- tableGrob(df2,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)
tab3 <- tableGrob(df3,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)

g1 <- combine(tab1,tab2,along = 2)# 1st combine operation 
g2 <- combine(g1,tab3,along = 1)#second combine operation

grid.arrange(g2)
```

The output is missing a table from the g1 tableGrob object.

[image]

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combine family of functions is largely experimental; I stole it from gtable where it had a few more bugs, but it's still not fully functional.
The logic, IIRC, is to align based on row/column names. This is where the combined g1 table is problematic because its row names are not unique. Fix them, and it works fine,

```
g1$rownames <- paste0("r", seq_len(nrow(g1)))
```

[image]

(needless to say, PR are welcome)

Comment: Thanks. This works great. ^-^. Will you add that to your next version of combine()/gridExtra ? - Cheers

Comment: I don't know, gridExtra has become very low priority for me, especially when it comes to features that belong to gtable. Pull requests on the other hand could convince me.

Answer (score 0):

You could rbind the two data frames like this?

```
alphabets <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",3))
numbers <- c(rep(c(1,2,3), 3))

df1 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets[1:4],numbers=numbers[1:4])
df2 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets[1:4],numbers=numbers[1:4])
df3 <- data.frame(alphabets = alphabets,numbers=numbers)

tab1 <- tableGrob(df1,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)
tab2 <- tableGrob(df2,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)
tab3 <- tableGrob(df3,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)

df4 <- rbind(df1,df2)
tab4 <- tableGrob(df4,theme = ttheme_default(),row=NULL)

g2 <- combine(tab4,tab3,along = 1)#second combine operation
grid.arrange(g2)
```

You could hack it and make a row between the two data frames with the header that you want

Comment: Thanks. That is an hackish work around. I thought of doing something like that. But still it still does not resolve our problem with the combine() function